# How to filter Profiler Instrument by thread

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, instruments

Want to debug how much of my main thread is being used in Time Profiler to gauge how much of my main thread is being used during app start. Is there a way to filter the Profiler instrument by thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Time Profiler groups everything by thread. You can tap the arrow next to a thread to drill down to just that thread if you want.

Comment: @jfisk Above the graph on the left side, you should see a group of three small buttons. Click the right button to separate the Time Profiler instrument's graph data by thread. There are menus next to the buttons to filter what appears in the graph.